# converting text sent to std::ostream

Tags: c++, stream, std

I have a function that sends stuff to `std::ostream`.
Something like this

```
void f(std::ostream& oss) {
    oss << "Hello world!";
}
```

Now, I would like to create my own class that derives from `std::ostream` that would be parsing outgoing text, and changing it, so it would print "Ola world!", for example.

```
class StreamConverted : public std::ostream {
...
};
```

I believe (I am not too experienced with stream manipulation) that I would have to 'play' with the underlying `rdbuf()` of the stream, so I would have to substitute `rdbuf` of `std::ostream` with mine.

```
MyStreamBuf     m_my_streambuf;
std::ostream&   m_original_stream
std::streambuf* m_original_streambuf;

public:
    StreamConverted(std::ostream& os)
    : m_original_stream(os)
    , m_original_streambuf(os.rdbuf(&m_my_streambuf))
    {}
```

(Please, forgive me any obvious mistakes or typos. I am writing this all on the flight. I would also add destructor to restore original streambuf.)

This leads me to the need to write my `MyStreamBuf` that would derive from `std::streambuf`

```
class MyStreamBuf : public std::streambuf {
};
```

**And here comes the moment when I need an advice.**

Should I create my own buffer by calling `std::streambuf::setp(begin, end)` and then overwrite the `overflow()` method to parse the contents of the buffer when it is called, and then send the data out to the original streambuf after 'in some reasonable way' transforming the buffer?

I am not sure if I am going to far with modifying the buffer instead of doing something with `ostream`...

Any advice?

Comment: This really doesn't seem to me to be something the stream should be doing - I would say `oss << translate("Hello world!");` would be a much better design choice.

Comment: There is no need to derive a custom `ostream` class, just a custom `streambuf` (which you might derive from `std::stringbuf` to help you), which you can then use with the standard `std::ostream` via its `basic_streambuf*` constructor or `rdbuf()` setter. Do your translation in your `streambuf` class' `sync()` method before sending it off to whatever output you want it to write to.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I don't have actually a freedom to do `oss << translate`, as I am not the owner of the `f()` function, and I am the middle man that catches output of one stream, and sends to the other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That sounds very interesting!